# how to retrieve only current date data from SQLite database?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm storing the date and time in SQLite Db. I want to retrieve only data of current data. I have search internet for a solution but I couldn't find any answers.

My code:

Creating Table

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        final String query = "CREATE TABLE " + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TABLE_NAME +" ("
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.MONEY+ " REAL NOT NULL,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.CAT+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TIMESTAMP+" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"+"); " ;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Retrieving all data :

```
   private Cursor getAllData()
    {
        return db.query(Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TIMESTAMP);
    }
```

Here I want to retrieve  only the data of current date

Comment: Hint:  `where date(col) = date('now')`.

Comment: can give more information?

Comment: My problem has been solved. After doing some more research on the internet    
 Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ "= date('now', 'localtime')"
  I have used this to get the current date records. Thanks for your help